# In GCP Dataflow/Apache Beam Python SDK, is there a time limit for DoFn.process?

Tags: python, timeout, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-internals

In Apache Beam Python SDK running on GCP Dataflow, I have a `DoFn.process` that takes a long time. My DoFn takes a long time for reasons that are not that important - I have to accept them due to requirements out of my control. But if you must know, it is making network calls to external services that take quite long (several seconds) and it is processing multiple elements from a previous `GroupByKey` - leading to `DoFn.process` calls that takes minutes.

Anyways, my question is: Is there a time limit for the runtime length of a `DoFn.process` call? I'm asking because I'm seeing logs that look like:

```
WARNING 2023-01-03T13:12:12.679957Z ReportProgress() took long: 1m49.15726646s
WARNING 2023-01-03T13:12:14.474585Z ReportProgress() took long: 1m7.166061638s
WARNING 2023-01-03T13:12:14.864634Z ReportProgress() took long: 1m58.479671042s
WARNING 2023-01-03T13:12:16.967743Z ReportProgress() took long: 1m40.379289919s
2023-01-03 08:16:47.888 EST Error message from worker: SDK harness sdk-0-6 disconnected.
2023-01-03 08:21:25.826 EST Error message from worker: SDK harness sdk-0-2 disconnected.
2023-01-03 08:21:36.011 EST Error message from worker: SDK harness sdk-0-4 disconnected.
```

It seems to me like the Apache Beam Fn API Progress Reporting machinery thinks that my `DoFn.process` function is stuck not making any progress and eventually terminates the "unresponsive" SDK Harness. Is this happening because my `DoFn.process` is taking too low to process a single element? If so how do I report progress to the Dataflow Worker Engine to let it know that my `DoFn.process` is still alive?

Comment: I'm most familiar with the Beam Java SDK and one pattern I have seen there is to maintain pending jobs as state within the DoFn, and then to wait on completion of those jobs as part of the FinishBundle method. BigQueryIO's [WriteTables](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/WriteTables.java) is an example of this. I have run Dataflow pipelines that end up needing to wait many minutes for BigQuery load jobs to complete.

Comment: Hi @cozos, it seems to be some memory pressure is there. Can you please add `--dataflow_service_options=enable_google_cloud_profiler` to the options so that you can have a better look of the cpu and memory usage? Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Does GCP have memory profiling for Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **no** time limit for the runtime length of a DoFn.process call. However there is a related thing. Pipelines running on Dataflow regularly reports progress if this progress reporting fails for a long time, Dataflow service will assume the related workers failed and cancels work assigned to those workers.

In Python, this might happen if for some reason progress reporting thread is not scheduled (e.g. holding the GIL for a long time, or something consuming all CPU.). See https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors for more information on this (paragraph starting with "In Python pipelines, this error might occur when workers use too much CPU.").